# SMTP configuration issue in drupal 7

Tags: 7, emails

In SMTP module configuration I have set the following fields:

```
SMTP Server: smtp.live.com
SMTP port:25
Use encrypted protocol: NO
```

In `E-MAIL OPTIONS`,

```
E-mail from address: myadress@hotmail.com
SEND TEST E-MAIL: myadress@hotmail.com.
```

but it gives me the long detail of errors with the last line `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.` Same error when I try to use below configuration:

```
 SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
 SMTP port:25
 Use encrypted protocol: SSL
```

In `E-MAIL OPTIONS`,

```
E-mail from address: my_gmail_address
SEND TEST E-MAIL: my_another_address.
```

But when I used port 80 instead of 25 then it gives me the following error for `SMTP.live.com`

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) drupal 7
```

**UPDATED:**

Below is the screen shot for gmail configuration.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change Port number to 465 or 587 in case of `SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com` and 587 in case of `SMTP Server: smtp.live.com`.

As per : https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html.

Comment: In case of 587 on `SMTP.live.com` it gives me same large number of error lines with a last line `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate`. And for `SMTP.gmail.com` and `port:587` with same configuration above , it causes the following error`SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.`

Comment: Can you please share your screenshot of configuration too?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Are you getting mail along with errors? Uncheck the "Enable debugging" option and see.

Comment: No I am not getting any email, if I unchecked the "Enable Debugging" option then I get the `SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.` on sending email